# What's "PDF Chain" in TeXstudio, and how to modify it?

Tags: bibtex, texstudio

I basically want to modify the `Build & View` command to include `bibtex` in its steps. The default option is `PDF Chain`, which I thought could be broken down into more steps and added `bibtex` to it. However, I cannot find `PDF Chain` in the Edit Command panel.

So what steps does `PDF Chain` stand for? Can it be edited? If not, how do I modify the `F1 - Build & View` so that it includes `bibtex`?

EDIT: Add picture of my Configure Build panel.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **Show advanced options**. See the image below. You can edit almost everything. Go to *Options* menu. On the *Build* tab you can see the `pdfchain`.

I guess that what you want is

```
txs:///pdflatex | txs:///bibtex | txs:///pdflatex | txs:///pdflatex | txs:///view-pdf
```

[image]

Comment: My Build panel looks different as in my edit... (I'm using TeXstudio 2.5.2 on Ubuntu 12.04). I can edit what the `Build & View` does, but have no idea what is `PDF Chain`

Comment: @Heisenberg, see my edited post.

Comment: How do you exploit the "Repeat" function? In your screenshot I see all the repeat buttons are off. Turning it on means "Repeat contained compilation commands" (however I'm not really sure how it is "repeated". Turning it on works perfectly for me for any first run from scratch (or after deleting all auxiliary files), but if I made a small change in citation or heading structure, I'll still need to Build several times. My current building chain is : txs:///bibtex | txs:///compile | txs:///view

Comment: @JimRaynor, to be tru I don't use those button. But try to add another `compile` before `bibtex`.

Comment: Thank you, the full chain: `txs:///compile | txs:///bibliography | txs:///compile | txs:///compile | txs:///view` would work perfectly in any build call, while the "incomplete" chain with repeat function turned on only performs well on the cold build (without any auxiliary files), on the rebuilt, it may have some trouble with rearranging the citation order.