# makeindex is not called when compiling in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio

I compile my project using TeXstudio. This works fine except for the index. The idx-file is generated by there is always a warning saying No file MYFILE.ind.
If I call `makeindex MYFILE.idx` from cmd the ind file is generated. Seems to me that makeindex is not called during compilation. How can make makeindex called during compilation process?

Edit: Considering the answer it now compiles indices from within TeXstudio. Hope this helps.

[image: My updated configuration settings]

Comment: I don't think makeindex is included in the automatic compilation, this answer will show you where to look if you want to change it: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/208532/3929, usually it is just easier to hit F12 manually

Comment: Thank you, I changed "txs:///pdflatex" to "txs:///pdflatex | txs:///makeindex" in order to have it called from within the build chain. This works if I compile twice. I checked the icon the compile it twice automatically but it still does not work in the first run. I guess this is supposed to be like this?!

Comment: Pass, I do not use this editor, for the most part I compile using the latexmk script (direct part of TeX Live), it handles all compilation, bibtex, makeindex whenever needed

Comment: You probably need to figure out exactly what `txs:///compile` does.

Comment: `txs:///pdflatex | txs:///makeindex | txs:///pdflatex` already works in one run, `txs:///latexmk` wants me to install Perl. Can you link a post on how to do that properly?

Comment: Use TeX Live instead of MikTeX, I cannot advise you on how to use `latexmk` or install Perl on windows. With TeX Live it is included on windows and works out of the box. Note that compile does more that that, it does some analysis to see whether to run several times. That is where you might want to change things, I do not know there.

Comment: that's right. Unless you'd want to go by something like `txs:///latexmk | txs:///makeindex | txs:///view` then I don't see how it would be any different

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is still relevant, but in the latest version of TeXstudio, namely v2.12.6, you can compile the index under `>Tools>Index`.